# Columba folder w/mountain 10sp cassette & Sram X7 derailleur

Tags: frames, mechanical, dropouts

On my bike the derailleur mounting bracket (hanger) is held by the hub axle and therefore fills some of the dropout slot on one side and pushes the axle lower in the slot on that side. So the axle is braced in its recess on that side, but not on the other side. This can cause the wheel to go crooked when I hit a bump and it's hard to get the quick-release skewer tight enough to prevent it.

To me it seems like a dummy dropout-filler is needed for the other side to balance the support the mounting bracket adds  -- or else a solid axle core that can bolt the wheel on tighter. Where can I get such a filler or what are my chances to convert the hub to a solid core axle?

Comment: What do you mean "not equally recessed"? Just that you need the hanger in place when you put the wheel in? The derailleur hanger shouldn't cause the wheel to move. Could you post a picture?

Answer (score 1):

That shouldn't be happening - it sounds as though you have the wrong hanger on the bike. If you have replaced the hanger (or a previous owner has) they have probably used one that fits on the bike but isn't correct. You may be able to file it down to fit, but it's better to buy the right hanger.

For your second question, it's definitely possible to swap out a QR axle for a solid one. The threaded part of the axle is the same for both, so it's just a matter of getting a solid rear axle and swapping the bearing races and so on over.

If you get that done at a bike shop they will probably suggest replacing the cones and bearings, since those are fairly cheap parts and the labour cost of taking the wheel apart is most of the cost of that swap. Once they have it apart if there's any visible wear it's worth doing, and unless the bike is fairly new I'd suggesting doing it. It should add less than $20 to the total cost.